# Checked out a repo from remote but when I do a git status a file shows up as modified — how to fix?

Tags: windows, git

I am using Windows and Git and I had modified a file. No matter how many times I did a git add and commit, the file kept showing up as modified and i could not for example do a git pull --rebase. I assume I did something wrong and screwed up the local Git repo so I decided to clone the repo from github, into a completely new directory. To my surprise, even in this new directory tree when I do a git status the same file shows up as modified -- it is as if it is somehow modified in the github (remote) repo which does not make sense to me. Moreover, the version of the file in cloned local repo does not have the latest version of the code that i can see when i look at the code on github. How can i fix this? I am concerned that someone else cloning the code will end up with the same problem. (Apparently only I am seeing this problem -- I did not somehow manage to corrupt the github repo which leads me to believe this is a git/windows issue.) As far as what I think I did wrong is when I modified a file and did a git add, i misspelled the directory path by using a lower case letter instead of an uppercase and then adding one file resulted in the other, properly spelled path showing up as modified and vice versa. I don't know if a symlink on windows got created -- the file contents are identical. But one would think cloning (via Eclipse) into a completely new directory tree would make this a non-issue.

Comment: You've done a `git clone` to a new directory, and when you do `git status`, it shows a file as being modified? What does `git diff` show?

Comment: If you haven't touched the file, it' s probably that the EOL format of the file is changing because of your settings. `auto.crlf` comes to mind. If you `git diff` the file, does it show up as completely removed and added as a whoe? Then it's the EOL format, for sure.

Comment: If this is indeed due to your global `core.autocrlf` setting you can initialize your local repository by passing the `-c` command line option to `git clone` and apply an appropriate setting for `core.autocrlf`.

Comment: You might have a Git commit that contains files whose name differ only in case. For instance, commit `a123456...` might contain both `a/readme.txt` *and* `A/README.TXT`. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64171364/1256452) for more about that situation.

Comment: @torek: this is exactly the situation, lower case "l" and uppercase "L" and there appears to me no safe way to get rid of the lower case folder and its contents. It might delete both folders -- so far I did a git pull but i am afraid to push to github. i also commented on the related question you directed me to.

Answer (score 0):

I looked through replies but it seems like the basic problem is Window's case insensitivity and this caused some (to me) weird behavior. In particular, I simply could not delete one of the folders -- they were "entangled." So the simple solution was to delete the folder and its contents from unix which is case sensitive. Then I checked out a fresh repo and problems appear to be completely resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64171364/git-merge-on-windows-with-duplicate-files#comment113486543_64176557) that you discovered one commit containing two problematic files: one named `Login/Login.tsx` and one named `login/Login.tsx`.  This comment is on a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64171364/1256452); see [my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64176557/1256452) for a discussion of Git's method of naming files in its index, vs what your OS requires in your working tree.

Your solution—use a Unix or Linux machine, where you get a case-sensitive file system, to repair the situation—is probably the easiest and best way to deal with this.  If you can establish a case-sensitive file system on your own machine, that also allows easy dealing with this (see my answer to [another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59511102/1256452) for a macOS-specific way to make a case-sensitive file system).

Given that what you wanted was simply to *delete* one of the spellings, though, `git rm` should allow you do that.  In particular `git rm --cached login/Login.tsx` would drop `login/Login.tsx` from Git's index, without affecting `Login/Login.tsx`.  This could leave your *working tree* with an existing `login` folder, though.

It's important—at all times, really, but especially when working within a situation like this—to realize that Git itself doesn't actually *need or use* your working tree to make new commits.  Each commit contains a full snapshot of every file that Git knows about.  These files exist as "copies" in Git's *index*.<sup>1</sup>  Hence there are actually *three* copies of each file:

- A frozen version of each file appears in the current commit (whatever that commit's hash ID is).
- A "copy" (see footnote 1) of that version appears in Git's index.  You can replace this copy with different content, and the read-only copy in the commit doesn't change.  You can *remove* this copy entirely, and the read-only copy still doesn't change.  Nothing in any existing commit can or will ever change.  The index copy exists precisely so that you *can* replace it, or remove it, or whatever.  In effect, the index—or staging area, if you prefer this term—acts as your *proposed next commit*.  It's merely *filled in* from a commit.
- Finally, there's a regular, ordinary, everyday file.  This copy goes into your *working tree* or *work-tree*.  To put this copy in place, Git must use your OS's file-manipulation facilities.  That may require creating folders and files within the folders.  If those are case-insensitive, and Git goes to create a `Login` folder when a `login` folder exists, or vice versa, the OS will say: *nope, sorry, already exists*.  Git will do its best to accommodate the OS by using the "wrong" case anyway, and will create a file within that wrong-case folder—or perhaps destroy some other work-tree file that has the same name except for case, or whatever.

This last bit, where your work-tree files end up with the wrong names and/or in the wrong folders and/or end up overwriting similar files whose name differs in case somewhere, is a problem for *you*.  It's not a problem for *Git*, though.  Git just keeps using the index copies of each file.  The next `git commit` you run uses whatever is in Git's index.  The fact that your work-tree doesn't match is not a problem for Git.  It's just a problem for *you*, because the normal everyday `git add` command means *make the Git index entry for this file match the copy that's in my work-tree*, and if that's the *wrong copy*, well, that's a problem.

In any case, once you have a correct *commit* in Git as your current commit, and extracted into Git's index, you can do whatever you like to your work-tree, including remove large swaths of it, or rename folders, or whatever.  Get it set up however you like, then use `git checkout` or `git restore` to re-extract all or part of the current commit to your work-tree.  Now that you've eliminated the name-case-issues in Git's commit and index, and cleaned up or removed any problematic files and/or folders in your work-tree, Git can create correct-case folders and/or files as needed.  It's the process of getting the correct commit into Git that's painful, except on a case-sensitive file system.

---

<sup>1</sup>"Copies" is in quotes here because the files in Git's index—which Git also calls the *staging area*—are in a special Git-only format that de-duplicates content.  When the copies that are in Git's index match the copies that are in some existing commit, Git is really just re-using the existing commit's files.  Files with all-new content actually require a new internal blob object, which Git creates as needed; after that, the content will be de-duplicated as usual.